# Dynamic polymorphic type handling with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a class hierarchy similar to this one:

```
public static class BaseConfiguration {
}

public abstract class Base {
  private BaseConfiguration configuration;
  public String id;

  public BaseConfiguration getConfiguration() { ... }
  public void setConfiguration(BaseConfiguration configuration) { ... }
}

public class A extends Base {
   public static class CustomConfigurationA extends BaseConfiguration {
       String filename;
       String encoding;
   }

   CustomConfigurationA getConfiguration() { ... }
}

class B extends Base {
   public static class CustomConfigurationB extends BaseConfiguration {
       /* ... */
   }

   CustomConfigurationB getConfiguration() { ... }
}
```

And json input like this one (which I cannot change myself)

```
{
    "id":"File1",
    "configuration":{
         "filename":"...",
         "encoding":"UTF-8"
     }
}
```

I am parsing the JSON in Java with Jackson like this

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
value = mapper.readValue(in, nodeType);
```

I want to deserialize classes A, B and others from JSON using JAVA/Jackson. There are no type information embedded in JSON (and can't be). I can't use annotations on the classes (I don't own them) and I (believe) I can't use mixins since there are potentially arbitrary numbers of classes like A & B (and mixins are not dynamic). Good thing is that the deserializing code knows which is the correct custom class to use for deserializing (basically there is a known mapping from class to configuration class), but I do not know how make Jackson recognize this information when deserializing the JSON.

In short: I want to be able to resolve the deserialization type of the configuration object  depending on the surrounding class type by setting whatever is necessary on ObjectMapper. How can this be achieved?

Comment: I don't understand how the question asked isn't already answered in the provided explanation.  *Complete* Java code and JSON examples would probably clarify things for me.

Comment: @ProgrammerBruce: My question is rather simple: I have the necessary type information at the point were I instantiate the ObjectMapper, but am unsure how to feed them into the ObjectMapper. I added JSON-example and Java-parsing code. Hope that helps.

Comment: I still don't get it.  Is the example JSON supposed to deserialize to an A or a B instance?  Is the "configuration" for a CustomConfigurationA or a CustomConfigurationB?  There's nothing in the example Java data structures that matches what's in the example JSON.

Comment: @ProgrammerBruce: Concrete example: Given the JSON from above I want to deserialize it to class A using `mapper.readValue(input, A.class)`. This breaks because the deserializer doesn't know that CustomConfigurationA is the class to use when deserializing the configuration-object. There are many ways to do this in Jackson, but none of those seem to really help me out. Hence, I am looking for the correct way to configure the ObjectMapper so that when deserializing class A it uses CustomConfigurationA, when deserializing class B it uses CustomConfigurationB, and so on...

Comment: I do think I now understand much better what it is you're trying to achieve, yet I'm back to my first comment: "I don't understand how the question asked isn't already answered in the provided explanation."  You appear to already understand that custom deserialization processing is necessary, and appear to have already implemented it for half of the problem.  I don't yet understand why very similar custom deserialization processing isn't the solution to the other half of the problem.

Comment: @ProgrammerBruce: I guess the easiest/best way to do the custom deserialization is what I am looking for. All of ObjectMapper's customization options I looked at (including those above) seemed not to be able to achieve the desired effect. Maybe just drop me a couple of buzz-words and I'll have a look at those as well...

Comment: FWIW I posted a few examples of using Jackson for deserialization to polymorphic types at http://programmerbruce.blogspot.com/2011/05/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into.html.  But you already said, "Good thing is that the deserializing code knows which is the correct custom class to use for deserializing," so I really don't understand what the question is.

Comment: @ProgrammerBruce: Thanks, the last example helped me put the remaining pieces together.

Comment: Great.  I didn't initially point it out, because I really thought I understood that you'd already figured that out, thus I was confused about what you were asking.

Comment: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization
Intoroduced in Jackson 1.5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently the answer was to implement something similar to the sixth solution posted at http://programmerbruce.blogspot.com/2011/05/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into.html, which uses unique JSON element names to identify the target type to deserialize to.

Comment: The link respond as 404

Answer (score 0):

Good answer provided by Programmer Bruce!

I have a case of polymorphism in which I want to keep the domain objects as POJOs and not use dependencies on Jackson annotations.

Therefore I preffer to use a custom deserializer and a Factory for decising the type or intantiating the concrete classes.

Here is my code ...
(be aware that I have an Annotation Hierarchy which are in fact "User Tags" and not Java Annotations )

Here is the deserialization Method

```
public class AnnotationDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Annotation> {

AnnotationDeserializer() {
    super(Annotation.class);
}

@Override
public Annotation deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

    ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) jp.getCodec();
    ObjectNode root = (ObjectNode) mapper.readTree(jp);
    Class<? extends Annotation> realClass = null;

    Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>> elementsIterator = root.getFields();
    while (elementsIterator.hasNext()) {
        Entry<String, JsonNode> element = elementsIterator.next();
        if ("type".equals(element.getKey())) {
            realClass = AnnotationObjectFactory.getInstance()
                    .getAnnotationClass(element.getKey());
            break;
        }
    }

    if (realClass == null)
        return null;
    return mapper.readValue(root, realClass);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar, and ended up creating a generic polymorphic list serializer and deserialzer.  Here is the deserialize that I think will work for you:

```
    public class PolymorphicListDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<List<?>> implements ContextualDeserializer {
  private HashMap<String, Class> _typeMap = null;

  private Class _elementType;

  private static <T> List<T> getNewList(Class<T> clazz) {
    return new ArrayList<T>();
  }

  @Override
  public List<?> deserialize(final JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {

    final List list = getNewList(_elementType);

    JsonToken nextToken = jp.getCurrentToken();

    if (nextToken == JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
        if ( _typeMap.containsKey( currentFieldName )) {
          list.add( _elementType.cast( ctxt.readValue( jp, _typeMap.get( currentFieldName ) ) ) );
        }
        nextToken = jp.nextToken();
      } else if (currentFieldName != null && isEndToken(nextToken) && wrapperCount == 0) {
        break;
      } else {
        nextToken = jp.nextToken();
      }
    }
    return list;
  }

  public JsonDeserializer<List<?>> createContextual( DeserializationContext ctxt, BeanProperty property ) throws JsonMappingException {
    //In Jackson 2.6.3, this method is called once per instance and the exception is never thrown
    if ( _typeMap == null )
      _typeMap = new HashMap<String, Class>();
    else
      throw new RuntimeException("Unsupported version of Jackson. Code assumes context is created once and only once.");

    _elementType = property.getType().getContentType().getRawClass();

    //For now, requiring XmlElements annotation to work.  May add support for JsonElements (if needed) later.
    for (XmlElement e : property.getAnnotation(XmlElements.class).value()) {
      _typeMap.put(e.name(), e.type());
    }

    return this;
  }

  private static boolean isStartToken(JsonToken t) {
    boolean result = false;
    if (t == JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
      result = true;
    } else if (t == JsonToken.START_ARRAY) {
      result = true;
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Above answers depicts a solution however lack what actually used annotations mean. If you are curious about what actually these annotation do, idea behind them & why they are required please go through the below link. Its explained very nicely in it. https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization